# how to combine classes of two ms access aplication

Tags: ms-access, vba

My colleague and I decides to break the jobs into two, she design the GUI in MSAccess and I design the classes in MSAccess too. Now the problem is, we need to combine those files into a single file. How I can do that? Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: I think you need to reconsider your development strategy. It sounds like it's destined to result in problems and lost code.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the classes that you implemented are modules in an Access database, then you can import one user's work into the other user's database (doesn't matter whether you're moving the GUI or the code) with the import function.  Up to and including Access 2003 you would right click on the list in the database window and choose Import. . . from the context menu.

Comment: @Larry-is there any tool in which I can automatically list the files having a difference, then choose the files that are updated one?

Comment: @user335160 Have you considered upvoting or accepting this answer? Your comment is quite a different question.

Comment: You can try Total Access Detective.  I've never used it, but it claims to do code and data diffs between two Access databases.